# Simple Tab using idTabs

Tags: javascript, tabs, jsfiddle, idtabs

I created a tab using the plugin idTabs, and then when I click to switch between two tabs, I would like the background of the tab button stay white, and orange border on top. (Like this image):

http://postimage.org/image/8tzg9ij2f/

What i could do was leave the edge on the link, but actually , I want the "LI" whole.

Here scripts that i make, http://jsfiddle.net/VRjK5/

I did use this js script for work(idTabs):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var settings = { start:1, change:false }; 
  $("#full-tab ul").idTabs(settings,true); 
</script>
```

I want make a fade between it too. But i dont know how make this in js.

Thanks guys!